# CKeditor 5 and SimpleUploadAdapter not working

Tags: image, upload, vuejs3, ckeditor5

I have a problem with the SimpleUploadAdapter of the CKeditor. I'm using the editor in my Vue 3 project and configured the adapter like that:

```
simpleUpload: {
    // The URL that the images are uploaded to.
    uploadUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_API_ROOT + "/message/file/upload",

    // Enable the XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property.
    withCredentials: true,

    // Headers sent along with the XMLHttpRequest to the upload server.
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "CSRF-Token",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + authService.getToken(),
    },
  },
```

Here is my Spring Boot endpoint:

```java
 @PostMapping(value = "/file/upload", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(@RequestParam("upload") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            MessageDocumentDto dto = this.service.uploadDocument(file);
            if (dto != null)
                return ResponseEntity.ok(apiEndpoint + "/message/document/" + dto.getFilename());
            else
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ErrorDto error = new ErrorDto(new ErrorException(ErrorCode.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), "UploadFile Exception");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(error);
        }
    }
```

When I am uploading a picture I get the server response 200 and the image is uploaded to my server. However I still get the error "Couldn't upload file: test.jpg" and the picture disappears from my editor.
I did some research and noticed one thing: When inspecting the request in the network tab of dev tools I can see the response is empty until I click ok on the "Couldn't upload file: test.jpg" popup. It is like the respone is kind of too late? I don't know maybe somebody knows the answer.

Thank you!

Tried to upload an image with the SimpleUploadAdapter but it keeps disapperaing from my editor.